# Include Module Title when exporting to excel file

Tags: javascript, php, html

I need to include the module title on the first row when exporting to excel. I tried some ways but still not working. Either it wont appear or the excel button wont work. Help me please.

For reference, here's my code:

$(document).ready(function(){

```
    , dom: 'lT<"dt-toolbar">fgtipB'
    , lengthMenu: [ [10, 50, 100, 500, -1], [10, 50, 100, 500, 'All'] ]
    , scrollY: 320
    , buttons: [
        {
            extend:    'copyHtml5'
            , text:      '<i class="fa fa-files-o"></i>'
            , titleAttr: 'Copy'
            , exportOptions: { columns: [ ':gt(0)' ] }
        },
        {
            extend:    'excelHtml5'
            , text:      '<i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i>'
            , filename: 'Employee Job Hiring Info List'
            , exportOptions: { columns: [ ':gt(0)' ] }
        },
    ]
```

tried adding a customize{xlsx]  option but not working. Title should be added in the first row of excel.